# How do you change variables in a function without re-evaluating for plotting?

Tags: plotting

I have a function $f(x)$ that takes some time to evaluate.
It's straightforward to plot but I'd also like to plot it as a function of y where, let's say, $y=\sin(x)$.

When I try `Plot[f[Sin[x]],{Sin[x],lowlim,hilim}]` Mathematica re-evaluates the function with the argument $\sin(x)$, which takes a while and doesn't give the right answer anyway. (The limits are right at least!)

Other things I've tried: `With[{y=Sin[x]},Plot[f[y],{y,lolim,hilim}]]` but I get the Tag Protected error. The slash dot rule `/.y->Sin[x]` yielded nothing. I also tried `Block[{y=Sin[x]},Plot[f[y],{etc}]]` and I get the raw object can't be used as an iterator error.

I'm sure the solution must be really simple but I just haven't found it myself yet. Essentially, I just want to scale the dependent variable axis without re-evaluating the function.

Comment: The simplest way is making a list of values of the function first (using `Table` for example) and, further, plot it by `ListPlot`. So, you can re-run the plotting routing for some correction of the curve view without re-evaluation of the function.

Comment: `Plot[f[Sin[x]],{x,xLowlim,xHilim}]`. You need to set the limits for `x` since this is what you are integrating over.

Comment: Of course in your case the x limits won't be unique, i guess `{x, ArcSin[lowlim], ArcSin[hilim]}` gives you an idea of the problem...

Comment: 1) Tabulate `f[x]`, 2) Interpolate the data `fi[x]`, 3) plot `fi[sin[x]]`.

Comment: @Rom38 @ yarchik  Yes, I was resisting making a table of values and working with that because I like that generally Mathematica doesn't make you deal with discrete values. But none of the other suggestions work so far - the original function is always re-evaluated and yields the wrong answer. So it looks like tabulating is the way to go this time.

Comment: @netto, This always works for smooth functions, i.e. for 80% of frequently used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a slightly ugly solution, and perhaps someone can suggest a more elegant way!

Instead of writing $ f(x)$ as a function `f[x]`, I wrote it as a variable `f` then assigned a new function `g[x]=f`. Then I plotted `Plot[g[x=ArcSin[y]],{y,ylolim,yhilim}]`

What that works and `Plot[f[x=ArcSin[y]],...` does not isn't totally clear to me, but I think it's because `f[x]` is not being recalculated.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK or not?

```
 f[x_] := x^2;
Plot[f[x], {x, -.5, .5}]
Plot[f[Sin[x]], Element[x, ImplicitRegion[-.5 <= Sin[x] <= .5, x]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{f[x], f[Sin[x]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`